# Why does this query slow down when using a subquery

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite

I have an SQLite database with 2 tables, with one referencing the other:

```
> create table commenters (
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    <snip>
    displayName text not null,
    <snip>
);
```

```
> create table comments (
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    <snip>
    commenterID text not null,
    <snip>
);
```

There is an index on the commenterID in the comments table:

```
> create index comments_commenter_id on comments (commenterID);
```

The following 2 queries are practically instant when run separately:

```
> select id from commenters where displayName = "somename";
12345
> select * from comments where commenterID = 12345;
many results...
```

To me, the following query which combines the above into a subquery should be exactly as fast:

```
select * from comments where commenterID = (select id from commenters where displayName = "somename");
```

However that query takes tens of seconds to run. This query with a join is also very slow:

```
select comments.* 
from commenters left join comments 
on commenters.id = comments.commenterID
where commenters.displayName = "somename";
```

To me it seems like the database isn't using the index for the latter queries, because the results slowly trickle in. Is this a known quirk of SQLite?

Comment: `commenterID text`. This should be `integer` to match the ID it's referencing.

Comment: Oh my god I'm an idiot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need an index on `displayName` :

```
create index idx_commenters_displayName on commenters(displayName);
```

And an index on `commenterid`:

```
create index idx_comments_commenterid on comments(commenterid)
```

The `=`s is fine, but this is more colloquially written using a `join`:

```
select c.*
from comments c join
     commenters cr
     on cr.id = c.commenterID
where cr.displayName = 'somename';
```

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to speed it up. `commenters` is a much smaller table than `comments`. Also if `displayName` was the problem surely this query would also run slowly, but it doesn't: `select id from commenters where displayName = "somename";`

Answer (score 0):

The solution as pointed out by Stu was to change the `commenterID` in the second table to have type `int`.